# How to display only first item of list to mobile visitor

Tags: javascript, list, liquid

**Set-up**

Currently, I'm migrating my webshops from WooCommerce to Shopify. I have a year of coding experience in Python but am new to Liquid.

I want to,

1. display a horizontal list on all but the product pages
2. display only the first `li` of this list if the visitor is on mobile

---

**Code**

```
<main class="main-content js-focus-hidden" id="MainContent" role="main" tabindex="-1">
  {% if template.name != 'product' %}
    <ul class="banner-list-items">
      <li>
        item 1
      </li>
      <li>
        item 2
      </li>    
      <li>
        item 3
      </li>                  
      <li>
        item 4
      </li>          
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  {{ content_for_layout }}
</main>
```

This code is placed inside `theme.liquid`.

---

**Issues**

The code satisfies 1 but not 2.

Moreover, I understand that Liquid cannot distinguish devices but JavaScript can. I don't know 1) where to put this JavaScript or 2) how to refer to this list correctly to have JavaScript only display the first item if the visitor is on mobile.

How should I go about?

Perhaps it's easier to create 2 list elements inside `theme.liquid` and use CSS to hide one of the lists, dependent on the device used. Not sure if it isn't better to do this hiding with JS though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JS. 
Simple CSS should do the trick.

Create (for example) a specific class at the end of your stylesheet, using media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .hide-mobile {display:none;}
}
```

Then add this class in HTML to items to hide on mobile.